# How to convert a decimal fraction number into base 2 fraction number in R?

Tags: r, binary, decimal, radix

I need to write a function that converts a decimal fraction number into base 2 fraction number in R. e.g. `f(0.125) # 0.001`

**What I did:** I searched for the related functions in R packages:

```
DescTools::DecToBin(0.125) # ""
DescTools::DecToBin("0.125") # Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

0.125 is:

```
(0 * 2^(-1)) + (0 * 2^(-2)) + (1 * 2^(-3)) # 0.125
(0 * 1/2) + (0 * (1/2)^2) + (1 * (1/2)^3) # 0.125
(0 * 0.5) + (0 * (0.5)^2) + (1 * 0.5^3) # 0.125
```

The reverse side is the following and was solved here:
[How to convert a binary fraction number into decimal fraction number in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411025/how-to-convert-a-binary-fraction-number-into-decimal-fraction-number-in-r)

Hence, a reverse-wind or something new hack seems to be necessary to overcome the problem.

Comment: You can use `R.utils::IntToBin`, I suggest twice: once to get the whole, and once on the fractional component multiplied by some high base-10 number (e.g., `1e8`) to get as much accuracy as you need.

Comment: @r2evans This does not work for the fractional part. By multiplying it with 1e8, you get the integer representation of 10^8*mantissa. But you cant simply deduce the binary decomposition from that. What must be done  is to multiply it by a large power of 2 (say 2^20 to get the equivalent of 6 decimal digits). Bit 19 corresponds 2^-1, bit 18 to 2^-2 and so on.

Comment: I was suggesting multiplying and then converting with `IntToBin`, not just multiplying, sorry for missing that clarity.

Comment: `R.utils::intToBin(10) # "1010"` and `R.utils::intToBin(0.125) # "0"`. The function `intToBin` is with lowercase i.

Comment: @r2evans `R.utils::intToBin(cwhmisc::frac(4.125) * 1e8) # R.utils::intToBin(0.125 * 1e8) = R.utils::intToBin(12500000) = "101111101011110000100000"`, so what?